# LinqKit PredicateBuilder returns all or non rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I'm beginning to use [**LinqKit**](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)'s [**PredicateBuilder**](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to create predicate's with OR conditions which is not possible with Linq expressions.

The problem I'm facing is if I begin with `PredicateBuilder.True<MyEntity>()` it **returns all rows** and if I begin with `PredicateBuilder.False<MyEntity>()` it **returns non rows**, apart from what expressions I use! look at the code below:

```
        var pre = PredicateBuilder.True<MyEntity>();
        pre.And(m => m.IsActive == true);

        using (var db = new TestEntities())
        {
            var list = db.MyEntity.AsExpandable().Where(pre).ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        }
```

It should return the rows which has IsActive == true, but it returns all rows!

I have tried all the possible combinations of `PredicateBuilder.True`  | `PredicateBuilder.False` with `And` | `Or` methods, non of them works!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `And` extension-method does not *modify* the original predicate - it returns a *new* predicate representing the original predicate `AND`ed together with the specified predicate.

Effectively, your operations are not changing the predicate referred to by your `pre` variable,  meaning you end up with either all or none of the records based on whether you initialized the original predicate to `true` or `false`.

Try:

```
    var pre = PredicateBuilder.True<MyEntity>();
    pre = pre.And(m => m.IsActive);
```

If you are planning to`OR` predicates together, remember to start off with a `false` initial predicate.

```
    var pre = PredicateBuilder.False<MyEntity>();
    pre = pre.Or(m => m.IsActive);
```

Comment: OMG!! That's a silly mistake. I made the same mistake about `string.Replace` method 3 years ago!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign pre as said by Ani

```
pre = pre.And(m => m.IsActive);
```