# Difference between PredicateBuilder<True> and PredicateBuilder<False>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I have the code:

```
   var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Value>();

predicate = predicate.And(x => x.value1 == "1");
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.value2 == "2");

var vals = Value.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

If I have `PredicateBuilder.True<Value>()`, it brings back what I expect, but if I have `PredicateBuilder.False<Value>()`, it brings back 0 records.  Can someone explain what the the difference is and why in one scenario I get back 0 records an in the other I get what I expect. I already read the `PredicateBuilder` documenation, but it was a bit confusing.  I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that I am `Anding` predicates together?

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on that class, but I would suppose that your calls create an expression that is equivalent to `true && (x.value1 == "1") && (x.value2 == "2")`, which may or may not be evaluate to `true`, depending on your items (hence you get back "what you expect", whatever that is). If you start out from `false`, on the other hand, the expression can *never* evaluate to `true`, because anding `false` results in `false`. Therefore, the predicate expression returns `false` for all items and you don't get back any results.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Thanks. Here is the documentation: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325245/linqkit-predicatebuilder-returns-all-or-non-rows

Comment: I use True with "and" and False with "or" and I always get expected results

Comment: If you are using the LinqKit Nuget package the most recent implementation has changed and is created with PredicateBuilder.New<T>() which is equivalent to False.

Answer (score 11):

When using `PredicateBuilder` to incrementally build a predicate of 0 or more conditions, it is convenient to start off with a "neutral" predicate that can be added to, since you can then just iterate through the conditions and either `and` or `or` them together wth the last one. E.g.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Value>();

foreach (var item in itemsToInclude) {
  predicate = predicate.And(o => o.Items.Contains(item));
}
```

This would be equivalent to the more straightforward boolean logic:

```
var predicate = true;

foreach (var item in itemsToInclude) {
  predicate = predicate && o.Items.Contains(item);
}
```

Which would be equivalent to

```
true && ((o.Items.Contains(itemsToInclude[0] && o.Items.Contains.itemsToInclude[1]) ...)
```

Or `true && restOfPredicate`, which evaluates to `true` if `restOfPredicate`is true, and `false` if `restOfPredicate` is `false`. Hence why it's considered neutral.

Starting out with `PredicateBuilder.False`, however, would be equivalent `false && restOfPredicate`, which would always evaluate to `false`.

Similarly for `or`, starting out with `false` would be equivalent to `false || restOfPredicate`, which evaluate to `false` if `restOfPredicate` is `false` and `true` if `restOfPredicate` is `true`. And `true || restOfPredicate` would always evaluate to `true`.

**Bottom line**: Use `PredicateBuilder.True` as a neutral starting point with `PredicateBuilder.And`, and `PredicateBuilder.False` with `PredicateBuilder.Or`.

Answer (score 0):

How it Works
The True and False methods do nothing special: they are simply convenient shortcuts for creating an Expression> that initially evaluates to true or false. So the following:

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True  ();
is just a shortcut for this:

Expression> predicate = c => true;
When you’re building a predicate by repeatedly stacking and/or conditions, it’s useful to have a starting point of either true or false (respectively).

Info complete
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx