# C# predicate list passed to Linq Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, predicate

I have a long Linq `Where` clause that I would like to populate with a predicate list.

```
List<Expression<Func<Note, bool>>> filters = new List<Expression<Func<Note, bool>>>();

filters.Add(p => p.Title != null && p.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
filters.Add(p => p.Notes != null && p.Notes.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
filters.Add(GlobalSearchUser((List < User > users = new List<User>() { p.user1, p.user2, p.user3, p.user4 }), searchString));

notes = dataAccess.GetList<Note>(pn => pn.ProjectVersionID == projectVersionID, filterExtensions.ToArray())
      .Where(filters.ToArray()).Take(10).ToList();
```

However I'm getting this error:

> cannot convert from `'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<project.Contracts.DTOs.Note,bool>>[]' to 'System.Func<project.Contracts.DTOs.Note,bool>'`

Which is an error on the .where clause. Pulling out the .where compiles just fine.

Comment: I think this is the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436773/11325901

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop over your filters and run a test on each one.

You can do it with linq like this to return **true** if **any** of your filters are true:

```
.Where(p => { foreach(f in filters) if (f(p) == true) return(true); return(false)})
```

or like this to to return **true** if **all** of your filters are true:

```
.Where(p => { foreach(f in filters) if (f(p) == false) return(false); return(true)})
```

Comment: Add something about the fact that he is using `List<Expression<Func` instead of `List<Func<`

Comment: @xanatos yeah I added some comments :)

Comment: May be better served using `.Aggregate()` as well

Comment: @moarboilerplate - I've no idea how Aggregate() would help.

Comment: `.Aggregate(GetList()..., (list, func) => list.Where(func));` progressively filtering the list

Comment: @moarboilerplate - that would involve re-writing the entire data access framework -- seems like a lot of work to use `.Aggregate()`.  I do agree that `.Aggregate()` is cool, but I don't think I would go that far.

Comment: Good point since it needs to go through a query provider and not just linq to objects. I should mention you can streamline your answer into one example by simply replacing the conditionals and booleans with `return f(p);`

Comment: @moarboilerplate - no that replace won't work, the if statement is inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I know what I was thinking. `.Where(p => filters.Aggregate(true, (result, func) => result && func(p));` which shouldn't cause the translation issue. Your foreach is more performant, though, because it breaks out of the loop instead of running all the filters.

Comment: @moarboilerplate - oh yeah that works.  It has a higher coolness factor  because it uses Aggregate, but I agree it will be slower.  I could be the basis for a solution that requires all filters to be run.

Answer (score 11):

I think great answer from Hogan can be simplified and shorten a bit by use of `Any` and `All` Linq methods.

To get items that fulfill all the conditions:

```
var resultAll = listOfItems.Where(p => filters.All(f => f(p)));
```

And to get the items that fulfill any condition:

```
var resultAny = listOfItems.Where(p => filters.Any(f => f(p)));
```

Comment: This technique evaluates one condition per time, not all at same time. If you need evaluate all filters together, look at PredicateBuilder

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two errors in your code:

```
List<Expression<Func<Note, bool>>> filters = new List<Expression<Func<Note, bool>>>();
```

change it to

```
List<Func<Note, bool>> filters = new List<Func<Note, bool>>();
```

You don't need `Expression` trees here. You are using `IEnumerable<>`, not `IQueryable<>`

```
notes = dataAccess.GetList<Note>(pn => pn.ProjectVersionID == projectVersionID, filterExtensions.ToArray())
  .Where(filters.ToArray()).Take(10).ToList();
```

There `.Where()` accepts a single predicate at a time. You could:

```
notes = dataAccess.GetList<Note>(pn => pn.ProjectVersionID == projectVersionID, filterExtensions.ToArray())
  .Where(x => filters.All(x)).Take(10).ToList();
```

or various other solutions, like:

```
var notesEnu = dataAccess.GetList<Note>(pn => pn.ProjectVersionID == projectVersionID, filterExtensions.ToArray())
              .AsEnumerable();

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    notesEmu = notesEmu.Where(filter);
}

notes = notesEnu.Take(10).ToList();
```

Because all the `.Where()` conditions are implicitly in `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass an array of predicates to the where method. You need to either iterate over the array and keep calling `Where()` for each expression in the array, or find a way to merge them all together into one expression and use that. You'll want to use LinqKit if you go the second route.